# Javascript/Ajax/Jquery modifying a select record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a html table, the first column is a list of checkboxes (as many as the table rows) all have `id="checkbox1", "checkbox2", "checkbox3"`.... On the click of a button (`id="modifyLink"`) I need to find the first checked checkbox (not bothered if there are any after the first) and then open my modal (`id="modModal"`) and load a php page into it and post the value of the checked checkbox.

This is what I've come out with (obviously not working):

```
$function(){
    $("#modifyLink").click(function(){
        var checkbox = 'checkbox1';
        for(var i=2; getElementById(checkbox).checked == 1; i++){
            checkbox = 'checkbox'.i;
        }
        if(getElementById(checkbox)==true){
            var id = getElementById(checkbox).val();
            $(#modModal).modal('show');
            $(#modModal).innerhtml = 'load my modal with index.php/trainings/mod passing the id variable possibly in POST';
        });
};
```

If I'm going about this completely wrong can can someone suggest something completely different?

EDIT:

Ok I've studied in to this a bit more and gone for this:

```
$(function() {  
  $("#trainingRow").click(function() {  
    var id = $("#trainingRow").attr('data-value');  
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/index.php/trainings/showDetail",  
        data: dataString, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {  
            $("div#detailModal").html(data.html);
            $("div#detailModal").modal('show');
        }  
    });
    return false;
  });  
});
```

but why doesn't the div#detailModal html update? I've checked what the php function returns through a var_dump and its exactly the HTML code i'm interested in but I don't know why it doesn't work (the returned variable is called html and i json_encode everything in php before I return it).
A heads up would be nice, I think I've gone far with a bit of reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, my ajax was actually correct (the second time round). The problem was that you can't return variables from PHP even if you json_encode them. You need to json_encode them and the echo them!

Thanks to everyone for there input!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very ugly... but you wan't something like this (untested)

```
$(function)({
    $("#modifyLink").click(function(){
        var checkbox = 'checkbox',
            current = null,
            i = 0;
        while (document.getElementById(checkbox + i).length == 1){
            current = $(document.getElementById(checkbox + i));
            if (current.is(':checked'))
            {
              var id = current.val();
              $.post('url', { id: id }, function(content) {
                $('#modModal').modal('show');
                $('#modModal').html(content);
              });
            }
            i += 1;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much easier, if you're able to assign a class to all your checkboxes, say "myCheckboxClass".  Then all you need is this:

```
$function(){
    $("#modifyLink").click(function(){
        var checkedBox = $(".myCheckboxClass:checked").first();
        var val = checkedBox.val();
        $(#modModal).modal('show');
        $(#modModal).innerhtml = 'load my modal with index.php/trainings/mod passing the id variable possibly in POST';
        });
};
```

Alternatively, if you know the id for the table, e.g. "myTableId", you can do a similar selection, just replace the `var checkedBox` line with

```
var checkedBox = $("#myTableId input:checkbox:checked).first();
```

Comment: I do know the table id so i could work that cleaner solution. I will try tonight when I'm home from work (I'm in GMT+1). Is there a way to get the innerhtml or similar command to read from a url? Or is the best way to make my modal and have text inputs or whatever and then autocomplete them once i have the ID?

Comment: The only modal I've worked with is the jqueryUI dialog, which has a modal mode.  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form  You could make it a modal dialog and it would be easy to replace its existing html when the url you want has finished loading.  (Basically, when onLoad fires, change the content of the dialog's div, or just close that dialog and open another.)